# How to synchronously get JSON from API

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, asynchronous, synchronous

I am well aware of this code:

```
$.ajax({
url:'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/new_releases.json?page_limit=16&page=1&country=us&apikey=k4uaze4937mw3hf82upstxqw',
type:'GET',
dataType:'jsonp',
success:function(data){
    var movies = data.movies;
    $.each(movies, function() {
    $('#datalist').append('<li><a><img src='+this.posters.thumbnail+' class="ui-li-thumb"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+this.title+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">DVD Date: '+this.release_dates.dvd+'</p></a></li>').listview('refresh');    
    //get data from ul

    });
},

error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('request failed :'+xhr);
                    alert('request failed :'+textStatus);
    alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
}
});
```

The problem is that this code works asyncronously. And I would like to use

```
var lis = new Array();

// Iterate through the <li> items
$("#tag-cloud-list").children("li").each(function()
{
    lis.push($(this).text());
});
```

To get the items on my list (so I can determine if the data has changed). The problem is that the list is empty because the data doesn't arrive before I run this code ( because its asyncronous).

so I need a syncronous version of my code to get JSON from API. I basically this code to be the first code that I run and everything else runs after it. that way I know for sure that my ul is populated when I check for values.

I've tried the async:false, in the ajax call but it doesn't seem to do anything.

What I want to do: populate the page syncronously, then run my asyncronous code every 30 seconds to check/update the values put in by my syncronous script. Thats why I need both.

Comment: jquery ajax calls using jsonp do not support `async: false`, which is why that option isn't working

Comment: I don't think you're after a way to make this sync, I think you just need a way for it to work as async. Have you considered adding a loading spinner until the ajax request is complete?

Comment: How do I halt EVERYTHING until my async task is complete? Doesn't that the point of async task? Is there a syncronous method?

Comment: your success function will be called only after the request succeeds and data returns from server..and its always better you go for async methods